# difference between folder last modified date and current time in python

Tags: python

I have a folder, I need to check if since last 2 minutes, no changes have been made to it.
so I plan to check the last modified time of folder by using this :

```
os.stat(currFolder).st_mtime;
```

now how to take current time in such a way and subtract it so that I can know that since last 2 mins, no modification has been done.

I checked on google, but seems format of time was confusing to me.
Can someone please help on this ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `timestamp` to the python `datetime` object and check the difference between it and now.

```py
import datetime

def is_folder_updated(threshold_in_minutes = 2):
    last_forder_update_timestamp = os.stat('./').st_mtime

    last_folder_update_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_forder_update_timestamp)
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    difference = current_datetime - last_folder_update_datetime
    
    return (difference.total_seconds()/60) < threshold_in_minutes

is_folder_updated()
```